# how do i subtract two colums datetime type in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

```
df = df.withColumn('departure_time', to_timestamp('departure_time'))
df = df.withColumn('arrival_time', to_timestamp('arrival_time'))
```

I changed `str` type cols to `datetime` but I can't get subtraction

```
df.arrival_time = 09:00:00
df.departure_time= 07:00:00


df.withColumn(time_all , col(arrival_time) - col(departure_time))
```

I've got error

```
could not parse datatype: interval
```

Comment: are you sure `arrival_time` value is just the time part with no date part? if both columns are DateType or TimestampType, you can use [`datediff`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.datediff.html#pyspark-sql-functions-datediff).

Answer (score 0):

convert the timestamp cols datatype into a long value which gets time in seconds.
then just convert the seconds to timestamp.

```
df=df.withColumn('Difference',col("arrival_time").cast("long") - col('departure_time').cast("long"))

df=df.withColumn('Difference', to_timestamp('Difference')
```

Comment: why is the `to_timestamp` required? what if the subtraction results in 3600 seconds - in this case, a timestamp wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @samkart then the difference itself is negligible

Comment: 1 hour difference isn't negligible.

Comment: divide the timestamp by 60 to get minute difference, divide by 3600 to get hour diff and so on.